# Are these types of answers encouraged?

Tags: discussion

I have seen this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1986/does-youre-a-cantaloupe-have-any-meaning) in the main site. It has got an answer and accepted it. But I found there is nothing more than a link in the answer. I did not flag the post(till now) as "not an answer" to check here, if these types of answers are accepted  or not. It seems the asker did not make any [research](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) to get the answer. If we search google, the third [link](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&safe=off&biw=1366&bih=703&sclient=psy-ab&q=you+are+a+cantaloupe+meaning&oq=you+are+a+cantaloupe+meaning&gs_l=hp.3..33i21.64.8414.0.8721.16.15.1.0.0.1.1131.6121.3-10j2j1j0j1.14.0...0.0...1c.1.hRWD2Awjl1Y&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=8693c31e37b06527&bpcl=35466521) shows the result which is given in the answer also. And also citing a link only does not make a good answer. It needs further clarification and explanation from the answerer.

Comment: In light of your recent question that was closed - you might want to look at this http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: Movies and TV is one of the 'less pure more subjective' groups on Stack Exchange, but none the less a 'why is something so good' is usually viewed as too subjective.

Comment: Thanks @iandotkelly!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the answer is not great, but it is more than just a link - briefly explaining that it is a slang term and linking to a site that specializes in tracking slang.

It is objectively an answer, even if not of a high academic value nor requiring much research.  I am not convinced by an argument that it is not an answer therefore deserving to be deleted.

As for 'lack of research' for the question, well I am not convinced by that either.  The fact that apparently cantaloupe can mean something, would perhaps be one explanation for the term being used in that scene.  It is not a common expression, so I do not see anything wrong asking for an analysis here.  I would not close this question.

Comment: okay. I would remember!